# Remove part of the query string with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am not very good with .htaccess at all, so I want to achieve something very simple, but I can't. What I want to do is to redirect certain files to test.php, and if test is ok, PHP redirects back to original page. It works fine, I add the "test=ok" part to the original URL, that way I don't get a redirect loop. However, I want to remove the test=ok query part from the original URL on redirection. How can I achieve that???

**TL/DR**

I have several URLs I want rewritten through mod_rewrite.

examples:

http://example.com/?time=1&test=ok

http://example.com/?test=ok

How can I remove the **&test=ok** and the **?test=ok** parts using .htaccess?

Right now I have:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^test=ok$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)  /$1? [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|js))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !test=ok [NC]
RewriteRule .* test.php [L]
```

But that doesn't remove the **test=ok** part... :(

Comment: A question mark at the end with nothing behind it should remove the query string; but how do you think that would solve your problem? If you remove the indicator that the URL was "tested", then how do you want to prevent it from being rewritten _again_ on the next iteration ...?

Comment: Yes... that's true... I haven't thought about that... I just want the user to not see that a "testing" redirection took place. I'm just trying to send all files to an anti-virus of some sort to make sure they are clean, before served...

Comment: Wouldn't that better be done once, when the file is uploaded ...? (If you can't trust that uploaded files are not modified by anything on the system, then you probably can't trust a virus scan on that system either.)

Comment: Yes, but to do that, I have to do it on the Apache level. I want a solution that I can use on my clients' sites where they don't have root access to the server.

Comment: So how do you perform the virus check itself then? You are not uploading the whole file to an external service or something like that? (Because that would be really bad for performance, if you did that every time the file was requested.) Anyway, you could perhaps solve this by not redirecting back and forth, but by letting the PHP script handle outputting of the file contents as well, after it has performed the virus check - readfile, plus the appropriate Content-Type header.

Comment: I am uploading the entire file to an external service but through Ajax, it doesn't hurt performance. Maybe I will serve the contents through PHP like you said, using curl

Comment: How do you upload a file that is on the server via AJAX? AJAX is client-side, so the client would need to _have_ the file already. (And that would mean your virus check is performed only after potentially harmful data has already been received by the client.)

Comment: It's a complicated process using Ajax and phantomJS, which happens not when the request to the file is going on. Through Ajax I'm just sending the file location. The rest happens on the external service and it doesn't interfere with the request performance.